# Split a value in one column to two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in SQL that I would like to split a column into two columns on select (by a delimiter).  For example, the table currently has:

```
---------
Mary - 16
```

I'd like two columns as the result of the query:

```
--------   --------
Mary       16
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but look for [[sql-server] split ](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+split)

Comment: Usually helpful if you indicate the version of SQL Server you're using, and also which delimiter you're talking about. I assumed `->` but please be explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  left_side  = RTRIM(SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHARINDEX('->', col)-2)),
  right_side = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('->', col) + 2, 4000))
FROM dbo.table;
```

Ah, I see. `|` characters are column specifiers, not part of the output. Try:

```
SELECT 
  left_side  = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHARINDEX('-', col)-1))),
  right_side = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('-', col) + 1, 4000)))
FROM dbo.table;
```

Comment: +1, but I think that the `->` is meant to be an arrow showing the desired result, and that the delimiter should be " - "

Comment: @Lamak thanks, I've edited the question to make it more clear. I thought `|` and `->` were part of the data.

Answer (score 1):

If your not worried about edge cases, something like this will work:

```
Declare @Var varchar(200)
SET @Var = 'Mary - 16'

SELECT LEFT(@Var, PATINDEX('%-%', @Var) - 1), Right(@Var, LEN(@Var) - PATINDEX('%-%', @Var))
```

Just change @Var to your field name in the query.