# SQL Server : query to convert all row values of a particular column into separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with large number of rows. I want to select all values of one particular column and create separate column for each unique value.

For example :

[image]

into something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  left_side  = RTRIM(SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHARINDEX('->', col)-2)),
  right_side = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('->', col) + 2, 4000))
FROM dbo.table;
```

Answer (score -1):

hi you can use built in functions Left, Right or CHARINDEX etc.

Hope so this example could help

[Example one](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/25/sql-server-t-sql-script-to-devide-one-column-into-two-column/)

[Example two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561346/split-a-value-in-one-column-to-two-columns)

thanks